# Issue with creating event handlers for registered components

Tags: c++builder-10.2-tokyo

I have a package created in RAD Studio C++Builder 10.2 containing a number of new components. I register each component as follows (at the bottom of the `.cpp` file for a component):

```cpp
namespace Tmbdstringgrid_component
{
    void __fastcall PACKAGE Register()
    {
         TComponentClass classes[1] = {__classid(TMBDStringGrid)};
         RegisterComponents(L"MyComponents", classes, 0);
    }
}
```

These components have new event handlers eg:

```cpp
__property TNotifyEvent OnValueChange = {read=FOnValueChange, write=FOnValueChange};
```

After the package containing these components is installed, adding one of these components to a Form at design time, and then creating an event handler by double-clicking the event in the Object Inspector, I get the following:

```cpp
void __fastcall TForm1::MBDNumEdit1ValueChange(TObject *param_0)
```

Instead of:

```cpp
void __fastcall TForm1::MBDNumEdit1ValueChange(TObject *Sender)
```

Can anyone help? Why is it not displaying the correct names as defined in the event type, instead using `param_0`, `param_1`, etc?

I suspect it is something to do with how the component is being registered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code. This is simply a known bug in C++Builder 10.2 and 10.3 when using the Clang compiler instead of the classic Borland compiler:

[RSP-15602: When using CLang compiler with imported OCX the parameter names are not correct for events](http://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-15602)

[RSP-21807: Wrong parameter names in events for C++ components (used in Clang projects): param_0 instead of Sender...](http://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-21807)

[RSP-28047: Wrong function header created for callbacks from an imported ActiveX Control](http://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-28047)

Not sure whether or not this issue still exists in 10.4 and 11.0, but the tickets are still open.

Comment: I was hoping it was something I had done but thanks for the response.